# How to show all dates in the axis of a line plot seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a line plot using seaborn and in the image link I have attached
it seems like it did not show the required dates (daily) in the x-axis. How can I fix this chart?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.style.use(['ggplot'])
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

fig, g = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,6))
g = sns.lineplot(x="photosim_date", y="tdpower_mean", hue="tool_id", style="tool_id", data=df1, dashes=False, ax=g)
plt.ylim(80,140)
plt.title("L8 PhotoSIM SDET TDP Data")
plt.show(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the x-axis [tick locator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DayLocator).

```
loc = matplotlib.dates.DayLocator(bymonthday=range(1,32))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
```

Be wary that the axis labels will most likely overlap in this case. You can use [`fig.autofmt_xdate()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=autofmt#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) to automatically rotate the labels.

Comment: Sir Diziet, you are very helpful. Thank you for helping me out.